# here i got a problem where the code executes in the asynchronous way and temp variable is assigned by undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

```
for(let i of this.movieData.reviews){
          this.http.get("http://localhost:9000/getUserByUserId/"+i.userId).subscribe(async resp=>{
            this.user= await resp
            console.log(this.user)
          })
          this.http.get("http://localhost:9000/getReviewById/"+i.reviewId).subscribe(async resp=>{
            this.review=await  resp
            console.log(this.review)
          })
          this.temp={
                  "userdata":this.user,
                  "reviewdata":this.review
                }
                console.log(this.temp)
          this.moviereviews.push(this.temp)
        }
```

i want to make this in an synchronous way so that temp variable initializes with the given data and appends to the array

Comment: You seem to be using `async/await`, as such you should be able to do -> `await this.http.get(`

Comment: @Keith it's rxjs observable, you have to first convert it to promise to use `await`

Comment: You can use [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) to combine observables

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) (not tested):

```
forkJoin([
  this.movieData.reviews.map((review) =>
    forkJoin([
      this.http.get("http://localhost:9000/getUserByUserId/" + review.userId),
      this.http.get("http://localhost:9000/getReviewById/" + review.reviewId),
    ]).pipe(map(([userdata, reviewdata]) => ({ userdata, reviewdata })))
  ),
]).subscribe((data) => {
  this.moviereviews = data;
});
```